# Role based authorization in Business layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, claims-based-identity

I have a 3 layer application - 1) The UI layer is a ASP .NET MVC application 2) The Business layer is a class library 3) The Data Access layer is a class library. I used role based authorization based on claims. I set the claims in the Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var authenticationCookie = 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authenticationCookie.Value);
            FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(formsIdentity);
           // Get the roles from database
              ... 
             var role = GetUserRole();      
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;  
}
```

Now I have two ways to access the role in business layer

1) Directly access the role from the Thread principal

```
var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
   var claim = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == 
   ClaimTypes.Role);
```

**Pros:**

- Every method can implicitly access the role.

**Cons**

- Difficult to unit test since it is dependent on a static object

2) Pass the role as a parameter to the method needing it e.g.

```
 public IUserService {

    void CreateUser(User user, string role);
   }
```

**Pros**

- Easy to unit test since role is explicitly passed to the method

**Cons**

- Every method needs to have a parameter
- If authorization is changed from role based authorization to any form of authorization, it breaks the system

What is the alternative ? What is the standard way of implementing role based authorization in business layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard way of implementing **externalized**, fine-grained authorization (not just role-based) across multiple layers. The model is called [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) and stands for attribute based access control. There is one major framework which implements it and that's called [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml). Another alternative is claims-based authorization in .Net specifically.

ABAC/XACML defines:

1. a policy language with which to defines authorization rules e.g. `a manager can view documents they own`.
2. an architecture which defines on the one hand

   a. a Policy Decision Point (PDP) which processes authorization requests and produces decisions (Permit/Deny)

   b. a Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) which protects your application, intercepts business requests and sends authorization requests to the PDP. This is the piece of code that would sit in your app either as a filter, interceptor, annotation or more...

The nice approach with externalized authorization is that you can apply the same consistent authorization across multiple layers in one go (from web SSO to business tier and even data tier).

HTH. There are great resources on Wikipedia. You can also check out this [blog](https://www.axiomatics.com/blog) I try to keep up-to-date.

[image: The XACML Architecture]